# How can I render an array of components in react without them unmounting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of React components that receive props from a map function, however the issue is that the components are mounted and unmounted on any state update. This is not an issue with array keys.
Please see codesandbox link.

```js
const example = () => {
  const components = [
    (props: any) => (
      <LandingFirstStep
        eventImage={eventImage}
        safeAreaPadding={safeAreaPadding}
        isActive={props.isActive}
        onClick={progressToNextIndex}
      />
    ),
    (props: any) => (
      <CameraOnboarding
        safeAreaPadding={safeAreaPadding}
        circleSize={circleSize}
        isActive={props.isActive}
        onNextClick={progressToNextIndex}
      />
    ),
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {components.map((Comp, index) => {
        const isActive = index === currentIndex;
        return <Comp key={`component-key-${index}`} isActive={isActive} />;
      })}
   </div>
  )
}
```

If I render them outside of the `component.map` like so the follow, the component persists on any state change.

```
<Comp1 isActive={x === y}
<Comp2 isActive={x === y}
```

Would love to know what I'm doing wrong here as I am baffled.

Please take a look at this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-moon-9mswb?file=/src/App.js:468-526).

I believe I am doing something wrong when declaring the array of functions that return components, as you can see, ComponentOne is re-rendered when the button is pressed, but component two is not.

Comment: You just need to change the `key`. If `key` changes, it will get rerendered.

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets, not offsite resources, for runnable examples.  Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I forgot to include the "why" in my comment above: :-) Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. More: [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems:

1. To get React to reuse them efficiently, you need to add a [`key` property](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to them:

   ```
   return (
       <div>
           {components.map((Comp, index) => {
               const isActive = index === currentIndex;
               return <Comp key={anAppropriateKeyValue} isActive={isActive} />;
           })}
      </div>
   );
   ```

   Don't just use `index` for `key` unless the order of the list never changes (but it's fine if the list is static, as it appears to be in your question). That might mean you need to change your array to an array of objects with keys and components. From [the docs linked above](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

   > We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an [in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.
2. I suspect you're recreating the `example` array every time. That means that the functions you're creating in the array initializer are recreated each time, which means to React they're not the same component function as the previous render. Instead, make those functions stable. There are a couple of ways to do that, but for instance you can just directly use your `LandingFirstStep` and `CameraOnboarding` components in the `map` callback.

   ```
   const components = [
       {
           Comp: LandingFirstStep,
           props: {
               // Any props for this component other than `isActive`...
               onClick: progressToNextIndex
           }
       },
       {
           Comp: CameraOnboarding,
           props: {
               // Any props for this component other than `isActive`...
               onNextClick: progressToNextIndex
           }
       },
   ];
   ```

   then in the `map`:

   ```
   {components.map(({Comp, props}, index) => {
       const isActive = index === currentIndex;
       return <Comp key={index} isActive={isActive} {...props} />;
   })}
   ```

   There are other ways to handle it, such as via `useMemo` or `useCallback`, but to me this is the simple way — and it gives you a place to put a meaningful key if you need one rather than using `index`.

Here's an example handling both of those things and showing when the components mount/unmount; as you can see, they no longer unmount/mount when the index changes:

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useCallback} = React;

function LandingFirstStep({isActive, onClick}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`LandingFirstStep mounted`);
        return () => {
            console.log(`LandingFirstStep unmounted`);
        };
    }, []);
    return <div className={isActive ? "active" : ""} onClick={isActive && onClick}>LoadingFirstStep, isActive = {String(isActive)}</div>;
}

function CameraOnboarding({isActive, onNextClick}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`CameraOnboarding mounted`);
        return () => {
            console.log(`CameraOnboarding unmounted`);
        };
    }, []);
    return <div className={isActive ? "active" : ""} onClick={isActive && onNextClick}>CameraOnboarding, isActive = {String(isActive)}</div>;
}

const Example = () => {
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    const progressToNextIndex = useCallback(() => {
        setCurrentIndex(i => (i + 1) % components.length);
    });

    const components = [
        {
            Comp: LandingFirstStep,
            props: {
                onClick: progressToNextIndex
            }
        },
        {
            Comp: CameraOnboarding,
            props: {
                onNextClick: progressToNextIndex
            }
        },
    ];
  
    return (
        <div>
           {components.map(({Comp, props}, index) => {
               const isActive = index === currentIndex;
               return <Comp key={index} isActive={isActive} {...props} />;
           })}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.active {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Added a `key` value to my array and still have same issue that components are being unounted and re-rendered

Comment: I've updated my question with a codesandbox, I have narrowed my issue a little better

Comment: @KarlTaylor - I think the issue is that you're recreating your functions every time, if `example` is inside a component. (I made the same mistake when trying to do a runnable example for you.) I'll update the answer to show how to avoid that.

Comment: @KarlTaylor - I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) property in React. It helps React to identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity